# How get form in controller action Symfony 2

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, symfony, request

I trying to send Ajax request to my Controller, get form there, and if some data true, need to remove some part of form, but I dont know how i can get my form trought $request object. Help me please.

All code for now, I tell there is exist some way, to do something like this `$request->getForm()`

```
public funcion ajaxAction(Request $request)
{
     if ($request->isXmlHttpRequest()) {

      }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried setting the form action as `ajaxAction`? That way you can go on as described in the [docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#handling-form-submissions)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do something like this (I assume you're in your controller extending `Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller`):

```
public funcion ajaxAction(Request $request)
{
    if ($request->isXmlHttpRequest()) {
        $form = $this->createForm(new YourFormType());
        $form->handleRequest($request);
    }
}
```

after that you have `$form` with data from requst bound. You can call methods like `isValid()` or `getData()` on this variable

Check [documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html) for more info